# What are the advantages of using with() vs. calling vectors?

Tags: r

I am curious if there are any advantages of using `with()` rather than calling the vector name (aside from using fewer key strokes)?

For example, is `with(d,x1)` always equivalent to `d$x1`?

*where* `d` is

```
structure(list(x1 = c(-1.96300839219158, -1.7799470435444, -0.247433477421076, 
-0.333402872895705, -1.37145403620246, -0.23484024054114, -0.808080155419075, 
-0.359895157796401, 0.54316873679816, -0.687429214935226), x2 = c(-0.619089899920824, 
-0.0716448494478719, -0.136643798928645, 2.58777656543295, 0.758900617148999, 
0.687980864291582, 0.442931351818574, -0.734342463692198, 2.55862689249189, 
1.30677108261702)), .Names = c("x1", "x2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `with` is meant in order to evaluate expressions within the parent environment. `$` is meant in order to extract or replace vectors. In short, they have different purposes which in certain circumstances can overlap. Other than that, `$` can't evaluate expressions on it's RHS.

Comment: And of course `with`, `within`, `subset` and to some extent `$` are all intended for interactive use.

Comment: @Roland: Your comment intrigues me. Is there a preferred method for a "production" script or function versus using `with`, `within`, `subset`, and `$` interactively?

Comment: @AlexA. Yes, use `[`. See also the "Warning" in `help("subset")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just referencing an item in a list, e.g. a column in a data frame, then `d$x1` and `with(d, x1)` will both return `x1` from `d`. However, on its own the latter is rather unusual that's not really the intended purpose of `with()`; extracting a value from a list is what `$` is for.

The advantage of using `with()` is to evaluate *expressions* in the context of a single environment without worring about global variables or attached data frames making references to variables ambiguous.

The `$` syntax does not support expressions, so to perform a calculation involving multiple variables in a data frame, you would need to use `d$x1`, `d$x2`, etc. which is inconvenient. But for otherwise simply extracting an item from a list, `$` is preferred.

---

A notable case in which the two methods are not equivalent is as follows. Suppose `d` is defined as

```
d <- data.frame(x1=c(1, 2, 3))
```

Now define `y <- "x1"`. What happens when we try to reference `x1` using `y`?

```
> d$y
NULL

> with(d, y)
[1] "x1"

> d[, y]
[1] 1 2 3
```

`d$y` returns `NULL` since there is no column `y` in `d`, so there's nothing to extract.

And since there's no column `y` in `d`, `with(d, y)` looks for `y` in the parent frame of `d`, which in this case is the global environment. So this evaluates `y` in the global environment and thus returns `"x1"`. Even though there's nothing to extract, there *is* something to evaluate because `y` *does* exist, just not in `d`.

Now `d[, y]` gets us what we want. This first evaluates `y`, which turns this into `d[, "x1"]`, which is the correct syntax for extracting `x1` from `d` using another variable.

---

Some finer detail courtesy of David Arenburg:

Note that `with()` is actually a generic function that performs method dispatch, whereas `$` is a primitive. An inspection of `base:::with.default` is illuminating:

```
function(data, expr, ...)
eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
```

This serves to confirm that `with()` is for *evaluation*.

Since `$` is a primitive, it calls `.Primitive("$")`, which means that it calls an entry point in compiled internal code. Doing a bit of hunting shows that `$` goes to an entry point called `do_subset3` in subset.c. The comment immediately preceding that piece of C code is equally illuminating:

```c
/* The $ subset operator.
   We need to be sure to only evaluate the first argument.
   The second will be a symbol that needs to be matched, not evaluated.
*/
```

This serves to confirm that `$` is for *extraction*, not evaluation.

So in short, as David put it so well in a comment, `with()` and `$` have different purposes which in certain circumstances can overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer guys!

Comment: @User7598: My pleasure! And I give my thanks to David Arenburg for the great content suggestions that really made this answer thorough.