# Writing a function and calling variable in a data frame R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function with an argument that calls a variable from a data frame and I am wondering why the use of `with()` doesn't work in this instance?

```
#Data
N=100
p=2
d=data.frame(matrix(rbinom(N*p,1,.5),N,p))

#Trivial fxn 1
fxn1=function(var,data){
    # SELECT DATA
    data.new = data[with(data,var)==0,]
    return(data.new)}

fxn1(x1,d)   #doesn't work
fxn1(d$x1,d) # works
```

*Note1:* I asked this question: [What are the advantages of using with() vs. calling vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609830/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-with-vs-calling-vectors) awhile back and it seems like this would be a perfect use of `with` (but apparently it's not).

*Note2:* I also asked this question: [Call variable from custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467890/call-variable-from-custom-function) and received a useful answer which led me to write this function which does work:

```
fxn2=function(var,data){
    data.new=data[data[[deparse(substitute(var))]]==0,]
    return (data.new)}

fxn2(x1,d) #works
```

Comment: Please review the answers given below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than dwell on what doesn't work, here is function which *will* accomplish what you have in mind:

```
fxn1 = function(var,data) {
    # SELECT DATA
    data.new = data[data[[var]] == 0, ]
    return(data.new)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(rbinom(N*p,1,.5),N,p))
> names(d)
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5"
fxn1("X1", d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking I agree with Tim Biegeleisen but if you really want it to work you can use `as.symbol %>% eval` like this:

```
with(data, eval(as.symbol(var)))
```

otherwise you simply evaluate `var`. I doubt is worth all the fuss though.